# How to catch default values after a form was set to default in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, drupal

My form function

```
function my_module_settings($form, $form_state) {   
   $form['my_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Title',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('my_textfield', 'demo'),
    );

     $form['actions']['reset'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Reset to defaults'),
      '#submit' => array('my_module_settings_reset'),
    );  

    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_settings_submit';  
    return system_settings_form($form);
  }

  function my_module_settings_submit () {
    // Do something on sumbit.
  }



  // My reset function
  function my_module_settings_reset($form, &$form_state) {

  form_state_values_clean($form_state);

  // print_r($form_state['values']); 
  foreach ($form_state['values'] as $key => $value) {
    variable_del($key);
   }

   // I need to get $default right after "Reset" button pressed
   $var = send_default_values($default);

}
```

So, `my_module_settings($form, $form_state)` - is a standart module settings form. I added "Reset" button. I'd like to get an array of all default values ('demo' in my case) upon submission and pass it to the `send_default_values($default)` function. `$form_state['values']` contains an old field value right after "Reset" pressed, but actually the form has been changed to its default state.

Ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `system_settings_form` adds the reset button by default so you don't have to do that. Also, it restores the default values automatically when pressed. Moreover, I don't think you need another submit function because the `system_settings_form` will save the values in the variable table in the database.

**EDIT**: apparently in D7 they removed that functionality

Comment: I'm not sure that system settings form has reset button by default. Look at this http://drupal.org/project/settings_reset_button. The button was removed in drupal 7. Anyway, +1 for your replay

Comment: sorry, my bad. I had no idea they removed this functionality in D7